# Is it possible to have DDev automatically launch the site after starting?

Tags: ddev

Using DDEv I'd like to be able to run the command `ddev start` and after starting it would automatically open the site in my browser. I know I can run `ddev launch` separately but I'd like it to happen automacically.

I tried chaining the commands but that failed and I also looked at the post-start hook but couldn't get it to work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

(edited with full recipe)

Use a post start exec host hook that does ddev launch. Add this to your .ddev/config.yaml:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
  - exec-host: ddev launch
```

Comment: @CreateSean I edited to add full details of what I was saying, please try it again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to run `ddev launch` after `ddev start` – just run `ddev launch`. If the container is not running yet, a `ddev start` will be executed automatically as well.